# Testing for validity of a formative measurement model

Tags: spss, confirmatory-factor

I have developed a formative model which tests the relationship between two composites.

Obviously, I have to ascetain the validity of this model.

I am told that Confirmatory Factor Analysis (CFA) is the way to go on it.

1. How do I perform CPA in SPSS?
2. How do I interpret the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, I'm afraid - CFA can't be done with SPSS Base.

IBM sells the AMOS package which does Structural Equation Modelling - CFA can be done using this package.  I think this costs about $600.

Your other (free) option is to use R.

Comment: Thanks. Please tell me the website address for the R download. I know I can google it but I am unsure if it is the correct website. The last thing I want is to download a program that corrupts my data.

Comment: @AdheshJosh http://www.r-project.org/

Comment: Some CFA can be done in SPSS base package. I'm not sure if there is an agreed upon standard on how to conduct/test/validate formative measurement models either (so it is not like a magic solution is found in R).